# Google plus login windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, google-signin, win-universal-app

I am trying to add Google login in my windows phone 8.1 app. I am following the following tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3789b7/authentication-using-facebook-google-and-microsoft-account826/

I have created a project in Google developer console and added clientID and secret ID in app code. But on running the app when I tap on google , its not going to google login page.
Please tell what could be happening wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you really followed the whole tutorial? Just creating a project in Google Developer Console and adding the Key in app code won't work. Did you created the service and other steps that is mentioned?

Comment: yes sir @KrishnanduSarkar

Comment: check google callback url

Answer (score 0):

I have also searched for sign in using facebook and google in Windows phone 8.1 Apps and finally found solution from this link : [Web authentication broker sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

Maybe it will help you also.